# How can I use just the local planner?

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to just use the local planner?
My goal is just to detect obstacles in front of the robot and do some exploration.

Tried it in my own move_base class like that

```
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS costmap("my_costmap", tf);
```

I also made config files for local and global costmap, and turned static_map to false.
But my code always says waiting for map ...

Edit:
Now I also use gmapping to produce a map:

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
```

So my code runs and I only get a warning:

> You have set map parameters, but also requested to use the static map. Your parameters will be overwritten by those given by the map server

I now also have a message "nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid".
So am I right that I can use this message  and look for obstacles in the grid?
Or is there a better solution?

To just use the navigation stack is not an option for me ;)

Greets
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33882/how-can-i-use-just-the-local-planner?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2012-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to avoid using the global planner, there's a simple hack: use goal_passer in the navigation_experimental stack as your global planner. The goal_passer does (next to) nothing and just sends the goal to your local planner as it is.

---

Originally posted by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) with karma: 365 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1